# How to filter out errors / 0 from an Excel Column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Let's say that Column A performs some formula that results in the correct answer, error, or 0. I would like to delete the value of that cell if the cell is error or 0.

So far, my formula is `=IF(OR(IFERROR(ABS(G3816),0) = 0,ABS(G3816) = 0),"",ABS(G3816))`.

This does not work. It still gives me a #VALUE! error in cells where G reference does not exist. I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just filter directly for `""` or `#VALUE!` errors? It seems like you're trying to add a helper column?

Comment: @BigBen this excel file is part of a much larger automation. I will not have access to filter manually. I need a formula that I can apply to the whole column to handle errors and 0's.

Comment: If it's VBA, you should be able to automate the filtering.

Comment: @BigBen it isn't VBA and can't be VBA lol. Has to be an excel formula. I would think it's doable but maybe not

Comment: `=IF(IFERROR(ABS(G3816),0)=0,"",ABS(G3816))`

Answer (score 1):

As per @BigBen, `=IF(IFERROR(ABS(G3816),0)=0,"",ABS(G3816))`

Thanks brotha

Answer (score 0):

I used nested-if which works as an OR here; `=IF(ISERROR(ABS(G3816)),"to be empty - was error",IF(ABS(G3816)=0,"to be empty - it was zero",ABS(G3816)))'` and that works. Use nested if's if my OR's don't pan out. so it cascades down the possible outcomes.